# angular ng-repeat (key, value) | order by value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to order an array like this:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in sets | orderBy: value['ordering']"
```

This is my array:

```
[{
"item 1": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "1",
  "ordering": 1
},
"item 2": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "4",
  "ordering": 3
},
"item 3": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "8",
  "ordering": 2
}
}]
```

It should output: `Item 1, Item 3, Item 2`

EDIT: I need the key also

Comment: the angular documentation for [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is very clear on this.  "You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object", "If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to `ngRepeat`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what you have as an array.

Your array consists of one big object and you can't order an object in javascript. Fix structure so you have array of multiple objects.

```
[{
  "item": 1,
  "type": "text",
  "value": "1",
  "ordering": 1
}, {
  "item": 2,
  "type": "text",
  "value": "4",
  "ordering": 3
}, {
  "item": 3,
  "type": "text",
  "value": "8",
  "ordering": 2
}]
```

Then you can use regular array repeater

```
ng-repeat="set in sets | orderBy: 'ordering'"
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I cant change the structure. Do you know if this is possible with custom filter?

Comment: 2 choices, map the data to array or use utility suggested in other answer. Mapping to array is not difficult

Comment: Hese, yes you can use filter. Filter is any function in fact. obj in ( map | myMapToArray)

Answer (score 0):

I you don't need the `key`, you might wan't to give a try to this:

https://github.com/fmquaglia/ngOrderObjectBy

Comment: I need to use the key